# PHP: Problem with str_replace

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace, replace

I have noticed a strange behaviour of a **str_replace** function.
Can you tell me why instead of number 3 in **no_2** i get **no_4** ?

Here is the case:

```
$pattern = array(1,2,3);
$change = array(1,3,4); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE no_1 IN (%s) AND no_2 IN (%s) AND no_3 IN (%s)";

$test_multiply[] = str_replace($pattern, $change, $sql);
```

Which gives:

```
Array ( [0] => SELECT * FROM %s WHERE no_1 IN (%s) AND no_4 IN (%s) AND no_4 IN (%s) )
```

Can you tell me what should I do to receive no_3 instead of no_2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation for [**`str_replace()`**](https://www.php.net/str_replace) says *(quoting)* :

> Because **str_replace()** replaces left to
> right, it might replace a previously
> inserted value when doing multiple
> replacements.

I believe you are precisely in this situation  :

- Your `no_2` gets replaced to `no_3` -- because of the **second** item in your `$pattern` and `$change` arrays
- But, then, that `no_3` gets replaced to `no_4` -- because of the **thid** item in your `$pattern` and `$change` arrays

To avoid that specific situation, you might try reversing the order of the items in those two arrays :

```
$pattern = array(3, 2, 1);
$change = array(4, 3, 1);
```

And you'd get the following result :

```
SELECT * FROM %s WHERE no_1 IN (%s) AND no_3 IN (%s) AND no_4 IN (%s)
```

Comment: OK. Then what's the solution to this situation?

Comment: That explenation was exactly what I needed. Thank you very much Martin!

Answer (score 3):

If you use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) with an array of needles, every needle is replaced in a separate `str_replace` call. You can imagine that something like this happens internally:

```
for ($i=0, $n=min(count($pattern),count($change)); $i<$n; $i++) {
    $sql = str_replace($pattern[$i], $change[$i], $sql);
}
```

So in the first iteration all `1` are replaced by `1`, then all `2` are replaced by `3`, and then all `3` is replaced by `4`:

1. `SELECT * FROM %s WHERE no_1 IN (%s) AND no_2 IN (%s) AND no_3 IN (%s)`
2. `SELECT * FROM %s WHERE no_1 IN (%s) AND no_3 IN (%s) AND no_3 IN (%s)`
3. `SELECT * FROM %s WHERE no_1 IN (%s) AND no_4 IN (%s) AND no_4 IN (%s)`

To do a simultaneous replacement, you can use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) and call a mapping function for each matched pattern:

```
function str_replacep(array $search, array $replace, $subject, &$count=0) {
    $combinedPattern = '/(?:'.implode('|', array_map(function($str) { return preg_quote($str, '/'); }, $search)).')/';
    $map = array_combine($search, $replace);
    $mapping = function($match) use ($map, $count) {
        $count++;
        return $map[$match[0]];
    };
    return preg_replace_callback($combinedPattern, $mapping, $subject);
}
```

I used [anonymous function](http://php.net/functions.anonymous) in this example but it will also work with [`create_function`](http://php.net/create_function).

With this the order of the replacement doesn’t matter. You can even exchange two values:

```
var_dump(str_replacep(array(1,2), array(2,1), "12"));  // string(2) "21"
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you're replacing 1 with 1, so thats fine

`SELECT * FROM %s WHERE no_1 IN (%s) AND no_2 IN (%s) AND no_3 IN (%s)`

Then, replacing 2 with 3, to get

`SELECT * FROM %s WHERE no_1 IN (%s) AND no_3 IN (%s) AND no_3 IN (%s)`

Then replacing 3 with 4, resulting in
`SELECT * FROM %s WHERE no_1 IN (%s) AND no_4 IN (%s) AND no_4 IN (%s)`

Maybe you should replace 2 with another value (not 3), which you can replace again later.

Answer (score 0):

Because once you replace 2 with 3 the next replace will always replace 3 with 4